# How to play "Slides from Thoughtless Time" by Franco Morone

Tags: guitar, acoustic-guitar, slide-guitar

I'm trying to learn the song "Slides from Thoughtless Time" by Franco Morone.
  The song is relatively easy to play. But there is one thing I'm not sure about.

My songbook says the tuning is DADF#AD. 
  According to the book the following notes (without the bass) are played with the slide:

```
-4--2
-----
-3--1
-----
-----
-0---
```

Is it possible to hold the slide in a way to play this with the slide? Or is 
  it only possible to play the higher note with the slide?

Any help appreciated.

Cheers,
  Christian

Comment: I don't play slide guitar, but it looks to me like you'd have the slide at the 3rd fret then slide down to the 1st fret.  You'd have the slide across the higher 5 strings, leaving the low D open, and you'd be fretting one fret above the slide on the high D.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can angle a slide to play different frets - it takes a lot of practice to make it sound clean, but for something like this where there is only one fret difference it isn't too tricky.

What kind of guitar are you playing it on? On a lap steel it is much easier than on a conventional guitar, as you have to twist your hand a fair bit.